# getting the e parameter from inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert an **onkeydown** directly as an attribute of an `input` tag.

problem is that i can't figure out a way to pass the event parameter?

(I know that if we use `addEventHandler` and stuff like that we can pass the events parameter but in this case i'm restricted to just directly modifying the attribute of an element tag.

I also cannot insert any arbitrary `<script >` tags

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="alert(event.keyCode)" />
```

That should work fine in W3C compliant browsers. The `event` object is created automatically (although I'm not sure if it will work in IE).

Comment: is the created `event` function-scoped?

Comment: Yes, it's scoped to the event handler function. If, for example, you called `onkeydown="myFunction();"`, where `myFunction` is a function defined elsewhere, `myFunction` will have access to an `event` variable.